# Variable expansion in ssh_config

Tags: bash, ssh

I've got some remotely managed devices as per [this description](http://www.tunnelsup.com/raspberry-pi-phoning-home-using-a-reverse-remote-ssh-tunnel), such that to connect from my server I type:

```
ssh localhost -p 2870
```

Since I've got a bunch of hosts I'm managing, I wanted to shortcut this so I could just type:

```
ssh 2870
```

I don't want to use bash aliases (since then I couldn't also use SCP and Ansible), so tried this in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host 28??
       HostName localhost
       Port %h
```

This fails since for whatever reason %h doesn't expand on the Port line (it will on HostName and others). So tried this instead:

```
Host 28??
       ProxyCommand ssh -v localhost -p %h
```

Here %h expands OK, and I can see it logs into the server OK (via publickey) but I don't receive a prompt.

Any ideas on how I could do this 'aliasing' in ssh config?

Comment: You can shorten that even more by using an alias: `alias s='ssh localhost -p'`. Then type `s 2870`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though the %h expansion just doesn't work in the Port directive.  If you don't mind filling up .ssh/config with a lot of entries, it's not hard to generate them dynamically (especially if you have a list, or they're sequential):

```
$(for port in `seq 2000 2900`
 do
   echo Host $port
   echo "  Hostname localhost"
   echo "  Port ${port}"
   echo ""
 done) >> ~/.ssh/config
```

Since we can look at the source code for ssh, it's possible to confirm that expansion is not performed for Port:

readconf.c: https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/dc664d1bd0fc91b24406a3e9575b81c285b8342b/readconf.c

Calls a function percent_expand for host and exec options - that appears to be the function that converts %h into a hostname.  The same function is called from ssh.c.  Interestingly, it looks like ProxyCommand defers expanding those variables until later.  It is not called for the Port directive.

https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/ed877ef653847d056bb433975d731b7a1132a979/misc.c

Comment: Thanks Ian. I did end up adding a bunch of entries, pretty much as you've demonstrated. But I'm still hoping there's a nicer way to achieve it.
Appreciate the link to the source code, that explains why the expansion didn't work as expected.